# Uncaught error: Cannot find module "./src/module.js" with importing flow type module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

The module.js is where my flow type module is, I'm trying to apply the code in my form.js by importing it from the node module "module.js" but shows the error Uncaught error: Cannot find module "./src/module.js". I'm not sure where the error is coming from since that's the only error I got.

module.js

```
function capitalizeFirstLetter(data: string) {
    return data.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + data.slice(1);
}

function titleize (data: String) {

    if (data === null || data === undefined) {
        return "";
    }

    let cleanTitle = data.replace(/[ \-_]+/g, " ");
    let words = cleanTitle.replace(/([A-Z])/g, " $&").trim().split(" ");
    let capitalizedWords = words.map(word => capitalizeFirstLetter(word));

    return capitalizedWords.join(" ").toString();
}

module.exports = {
    titleize: titleize
};
```

form.js

```
import app from "my-app";
/* code here */

render() {
    console.log(app.titleize("sample log"));
}
```

Comment: I don't see you are exporting your functions in index.js, and how are you importing them in form.js ? or i miss understood your question ?

Comment: Did you use create-react-app? Please post all the code.

Comment: @Mad-D updated my code, I used module.exports. It works when I remove the flow code but when I put it back it shows the error always.

Comment: There's not enough info here... where's the line about importing "./src/module.js"? Can you give the full error message?